# 1/4 to DI Box, DI Box XLR to Scarlett 2i2

Tags: xlr

I'm trying to plug my bass and piano into the Scarlett 2i2 with the XLR cable with the DI Box, but there's no input signal coming in.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Knowing what the DI box is & how you have it wired would help. 2. The Scarlett doesn't need a DI box, it has instrument/line inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**Bass**: 1/4 mono cable (typical guitar cable) from bass to DI. XLR cable from DI to XLR input on Scarlett (the XLR input on the combo jack).

Alternative: 1/4 mono cable from bass directly to instrument jack input on Scarlett (the 1/4 input on the combo jack).

**Electrical piano**: 1/4 mono cable (typical guitar cable) from mono output of piano to DI. XLR From DI to Scarlett (do you see the pattern here?). As Electrical pianos often are stereo you might like to have two sets of DI-s and cables.

Alternative: 1/4 mono cable from piano mono output directly to instrument jack input on Scarlett (the 1/4 input on the combo connector).